# Calculate Geolocation on line between two GeoLocations

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, math, geolocation, geometry

I have two known Google Geolocation points A and B. I need to return GeoLocation point C which is on AB line and on distance x from point A:

```
Geolocation returnGeolocationC(Geolocation A, Geolocation B, double x) {
     ...
     return C;
}
```

[image]

I know that I can use Haversine formula and I can calculate AB distance and therefore I also have AC and CB distance. Any idea or hint how to implement this?

Edit: Line is straight, no need to consider roads.

Comment: Is it a straight line path or might it follow roads?

Comment: It is straight line.

Comment: if `cos((long2-long1))~1` you can use a Mercatore (Cartesian plane) approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a really easy formula at [this link](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Intermediate).

Since you have the distance from one of the points and not the fraction of the distance on the segment you can slightly modify the formula:

```
    A=sin(d-x)/sin(d)
    B=sin(x)/sin(d)
    x = A*cos(lat1)*cos(lon1) +  B*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2)
    y = A*cos(lat1)*sin(lon1) +  B*cos(lat2)*sin(lon2)
    z = A*sin(lat1)           +  B*sin(lat2)
    lat=atan2(z,sqrt(x^2+y^2))
    lon=atan2(y,x)
```

where `x` is the required distance and `d` is the distance between A and B (that you can evaluate with Haversine), both divided by the Earth radius.

You can also use another formula for `sin(d)`:

```
 nx =  cos(lat1)*sin(lon1)*sin(lat2)           - sin(lat1)*          cos(lat2)*sin(lon2)
 ny = -cos(lat1)*cos(lon1)*sin(lat2)           + sin(lat1)*          cos(lat2)*cos(lon2)
 nz =  cos(lat1)*cos(lon1)*cos(lat2)*sin(lon2) - cos(lat1)*sin(lon1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2)
 sind = sqrt(nx^2+ny^2+nz^2)
```

It's more complex than the Haversine formula, but you can memoize some of the factors in the two steps.

---

As the OP posted a non working Java implementation, this is my corrections to make it work.

```
private static GpsLocation CalcGeolocationWithDistance(GpsLocation pointA, GpsLocation pointB, double distanceFromA)
{   //distanceFromA = 2.0 km, PointA and PointB are in Europe on 4.0km distance.
    double earthRadius = 6371000.0;
    double distanceAB = CalcDistance(pointA.Latitude, pointA.Longitude, pointB.Latitude, pointB.Longitude);
    //distance AB is calculated right according to Google Maps (4.0 km)
    double a = Math.Sin((distanceAB - distanceFromA) / earthRadius) / Math.Sin(distanceAB / earthRadius);
    double b = Math.Sin(distanceFromA / earthRadius) / Math.Sin(distanceAB / earthRadius);
    double x = a * Math.Cos(pointA.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Cos(pointA.Longitude * Math.PI / 180) + b * Math.Cos(pointB.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Cos(pointB.Longitude * Math.PI / 180);
    double y = a * Math.Cos(pointA.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Sin(pointA.Longitude * Math.PI / 180) + b * Math.Cos(pointB.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Sin(pointB.Longitude * Math.PI / 180);
    double z = a * Math.Sin(pointA.Latitude * Math.PI / 180) + b * Math.Sin(pointB.Latitude * Math.PI / 180);
    double lat = Math.Atan2(z, Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
    double lon = Math.Atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    //lat and lon are mo more placed somewhere in Africa ;)
    return new GpsLocation(lat, lon);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and put two points in Europe on 4.0km distance, and resulting point is calculated in Africa :) I implemented algorithm like this: https://gist.github.com/62filip/3f1b8f1c9c17aeb3b413   Did I get something wrong?

Comment: I fear it is a degrees to radians issue... try multiplying all the angles by `Math.PI/4`

Comment: And you need also to divide the distances by the earth radius (6371km): *In all subsequent formulae all distances and angles, such as latitudes, longitudes and true courses will be assumed to be given in radians, greatly simplifying them, and in applications the above formulae and their inverses are necessary to convert back and forth between natural and practical units. Examples of this process are given later.* (extract from the website I linked)

Comment: I multiplied all the angles with Math.PI / 180 and that did it. You have helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a good problem which solution will depend on the area of interest, for instance:

Consider the situation faced by a botanist studying a stand of oak trees on a small plot of land. One component of the data analysis involves determining the location of these trees and calculating the distance betwee
n them. In this situation, straight line or Euclidean distance is the most logical choice. This only requires the use of the Pythagorean Theorem to calculate the shortest distance between two points:

```
straight_line_distance = sqrt ( ( x2 - x1 )**2 + ( y2 - y1 )**2 );
```

The variables x and y refer to co-ordinates in a two-dimensional plane and can reflect any unit of measurement, such as feet or miles.

Consider a different situation, an urban area, where the objective is to calculate the distance between customers’ homes and various retail outlets. In this situation, distance takes on a more specific meaning, usually road distance, making straight line distance less suitable. Since streets in many cities are based on a grid system, the typical trip may be approximated by what is known as the Manhattan, city block or taxi cab distance (Fothering-
ham, 2002):

```
block_distance = ( abs( x2 - x1 ) + abs( y2 - y1 ) ) ;
```

Instead of the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle that was calculated for the straight line distance, the above formula simply adds the two sides that form the right angle. The straight line and city block formulae are closely related, and can be generalized by what are referred to as the Minkowski metrics, which in this case are restricted to two dimensions:

```
minkowski_metric =  ( abs(x2 - x1)**k + abs(y2 - y1)**k )**(1/k);
```

The advantage of this formula is that you only need to vary the exponent to get a range of distance measures. When `k = 1`, it is equivalent to the city block distance; `when k=2`, it is the Euclidean distance.  Less commonly, 
other values of `k` may be used if desired, usually between `1` and `2`. In some situations, it may have been determined that actual distances were greater than the straight line, but less than the city block, in which case a value such as `"1.4"`  may be more appropriate. One of the interesting features of the Minkowski metric is that for values considerably larger than `2` (approaching infinity), the distance is the larger of two sides used in the city block calculation, although this is typically not applicable in a geographic context.

So pseudocode would be something like the following:

```
distance2d (x1, y1, x2, y2, k) 
 (max( abs(x2 - x1), abs(y2 - y1) ) * (k > 2))                               
 +                                         
 ((abs(x2 - x1)**k + abs(y2 - y1)** k )**(1/ k)) * (1 <=k<=2)                
end
```

If `1 <= k <=2,` the basic Minkowski metric is applied, since `(1 <= k <=2)` resolves to `1` and `(k > 2)` resolves to `0`. If `k > 2`, an alternate formula is applied, since computations become increasingly intensive for large values of `k`. This second formula is not really necessary, but is useful in demonstrating how modifications can be easily incorporated in distance measures.

The previous distance measures are based on the concept of distance in two dimensions. For small areas like cities or counties, this is a reasonable implification. For longer distances such as those that span larger countries 
or continents, measures based on two dimensions are no longer appropriate, since they fail to account for the curvature of the earth. Consequently, global distance measures need to use the graticule, the co-ordinate system 
comprised of latitude and longitude along with special formulae to calculate the distances. Lines of latitude run in an east to west direction either above or below the equator. Lines of longitude run north and south through the poles, often with the Prime Meridian (running through Greenwich, England) measured at 0°. Further details of latitude and longitude are available (Slocum et al., 2005). One issue with using latitude and longitude is that the co-ordinates may require some transformation and preparation before they are suitable to use in distance calculations. Coordinates are often expressed in the sexagesimal system (similar to time) of degrees, minutes, and seconds, in which each degree consists of 60 minutes and each 
minute is 60 seconds. Furthermore, it is also necessary to provide and indication of the position relative to the equator (North or South) and the Prime Meridian (East or West). The full co-ordinates may take on a variety of formats; below is a typical example that corresponds approximately to the city of Philadelphia:

```
39° 55' 48" N 75° 12' 12" W
```

As you mentioned Harvesine, and also I am extending a lot, we can compare results using law of cosines and Harvesine, so pseudocode:

```
begin
      ct = constant('pi')/180 ;                    
      radius = 3959 ; /* 6371 km */                
      #Both latitude and longitude are in decimal degrees ;         
      lat1  = 36.12;                                           
      long1 = -86.67;                              
      lat2  = 33.94;                                           
      long2 = -118.40 ;                 
      #Law of Cosines  ;                                               
      a = sin(lat1*ct) * sin(lat2*ct) ;            
      b = cos(lat1*ct) * cos(lat2*ct) * cos((long2-long1) *ct);                             
      c = arcos(a + b) ;                           
      d = radius * c ;                             
      put 'Distance using Law of Cosines ' d                                             
      # Haversine ** ;                                  
      a2 = sin( ((lat2 - lat1)*ct)/2)**2 +                                 
      cos(lat1*ct) * cos(lat2*ct) * sin(((long2 - long1)*ct)/2)**2         
      c2 = 2 * arsin(min(1,sqrt(a2))) ;            
      d2 = radius * c2 ;                           
      put 'Distance using Haversine formula =' d2  
end
```

In addition to the constant that will be used to convert degrees to radians, the radius of the earth is required, which on average is equal to `6371` kilometres or `3959` miles. The Law of Cosines uses spherical geometry to 
calculate the great circle distance for two points on the globe. The formula is analogous to the Law of Cosines for plane geometry, in which three connected great arcs correspond to the three sides of the triangle. The Haversine formula is mathematically equivalent to the Law of Cosines, but is often preferred since it is less sensitive to round-off error that can occur when measuring distances between points that are located very close tog
ether (Sinnott, 1984). With the Haversine, the error can occur for points that are on opposite sides of the earth, but this is usually less of a problem.